# How can I flag a user's links to external websites on their profile?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags

I came across this profile and I saw a link to a website called codingWithoutComments dot com (**NSFW**), and I thought "oh this sounds interesting, let's give it a read", next thing I know I see some adult content on my screen...

https://stackoverflow.com/users/25/codingwithoutcomments?tab=profile

I see no way I can report this URL. I'm guessing it used to be a legitimate website that someone let die and now it's taken over by this NSFW content now... Should I flag one of the user's posts and explain what is going on? I saw no way of flagging or reporting a user's profile, which seems like something that could be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to flag a profile, no. Your best bet is to flag a post (any will do) explaining the situation with a link to the profile.

I've cleared out their website link now, and will let them know I've done so. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: It's on their network profile, too. Is that a caching thing, or do you need to manually remove it there, as well?

Comment: @MikeM. Oh, I didn't catch that. Unfortunately I can't clear that myself. I'll ask a CM to look into it. Thanks!